# Retrieving specific item from a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a list of JXHyperlinks, I need to retrieve them one by one and add to a panel

the code is:

```
for(int i=1; i<=lcol-1;i++)
{
    a2=sheet.getCell(i,0);
    stringy=a2.getContents();
    testlink= new JXHyperlink(new Action(stringy));
    list.add(testlink);

}
for(int i=0;i<list.getModel().getSize();i++)
{
    panel2.add(list.getModel().getElementAt(i));

}
```

the first loop is creating the list of links with their respective names (taken from an excel file).
The second loop takes the pre-made list and adds each object to a panel.
The problem is that id doesn't add them.

Comment: It's more likely that panel2 is either shadowed or not added to a displayed component

Comment: Nope. If I add components, like button and textarea before this function it works, but anything I add after isn't.

Comment: why? typically components are _not_ added to a list (tree, table ..)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `List` with `JList`. List#add is inhered from Collection, and adds a Object to itself.
JList#add is inhered from Container and adds a component to a Container. So Jlist#add its like JPanel#add

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are adding the `JXHyperlink` components directly to the list, not the list model.

```
for(int i=1; i<=lcol-1;i++)
{
    a2=sheet.getCell(i,0);
    stringy=a2.getContents();
    testlink= new JXHyperlink(new Action(stringy));
    // I'm the JList, not it's model :P
    list.add(testlink);
}
// I bet nothing exists in the model
for(int i=0;i<list.getModel().getSize();i++)
{
    panel2.add(list.getModel().getElementAt(i));
}
```

This is not how lists should work.

Instead, add the link `String` to the `ListModel` and use the `JXHyperlink` as a bases for a `ListCellRenderer`, then add an instance of `JXHyperlink` to the panel for each `String` in the list

See [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details, in particular, [Creating a model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating) and [Writing a Custom cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)